# Условие для hover эффекта

Tags: html, css

Есть меню из 5 элементов, ко всем элементам применяется hover эффект.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы 1 элемент меню статично был залит цветом, но при наведении на другие элементы, hover для первого элемента отменялся. Можно ли так сделать только с помощью css?

```
.cat_menu a:hover,.cat_menu a:active{
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background: #098DC4;
}
```

Comment: может при наведении на общего родителя?

Comment: Igor Xras  псевдо-класс, :not(X) может подойдет ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то при наведение на ДРУГИЕ элементы и без того отменяется `hover` у элемента, на котором мышь была раньше:

```css
.cat_menu {display:inline-block;}
.cat_menu a {padding: 1em; border:1px solid gray;}

.cat_menu a:hover,.cat_menu a:active{
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background: #098DC4;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
</div>
```

Если этого не происходит, то налицо неадекватная комбинация CSS+HTML, например, такая:

```css
.cat_menu {display: inline-block;}
.cat_menu a {padding: 1em;  border: 1px solid gray;}

.menu:hover a {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background: #098DC4;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
</div>
```

Если вам действительно по-какой-то причине нужно, чтобы при наведении на них ВСЕ элементы получали новый цвет, но ПЕРВЫЙ имел этот по умолчанию и терял при наведении на остальные (я правильно предполагаю, что это типа поведения активного элемента?), то это можно сделать, например, так:

```css
.cat_menu {display: inline-block;}
.cat_menu a {padding: 1em;  border: 1px solid gray;}

.menu a:hover, .menu .current a {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background: #098DC4;
}

.menu:hover .current a:not(:hover) { background:unset; color:blue!important;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="cat_menu current"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
  <div class="cat_menu"><a href="#">Menu item</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень сильно мне помогли

Answer (score 2):

Что бы селектор `~` работал выделенный пункт всегда должен быть последним в html. При это остальные пункты можно расставить произвольно, а визуально расположить их по порядку в помощью css-свойства `order`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.item {
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  border-top: none;
}

.static {
  background-color: magenta;
  color: white;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: magenta;
  color: white;
}

.item:hover~.static {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="item">Пункт 5</li>
  <li class="item">Пункт 4</li>
  <li class="item">Пункт 3</li>
  <li class="item">Пункт 2</li>
  <li class="item static">Пункт 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое